# How to source inline text

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptors, source

When you are creating tutorials online for people to use in a single terminal sometimes it's nice to source inline code...however none of these worked as I would expect. I would expect `foo` to be "bar" for all of these. Anyone know why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source <(echo "export foo=bar");
echo "$foo"

source <(cat <<< "export foo=bar");
echo "$foo"

source <(cat <<EOF
  export foo=bar

EOF
);


echo "$foo"
```

My only guess is that `source` cannot read from a file descriptor? I also tried using `.` instead of `source` same thing.

I am on MacOS, `bash --version` output:

> ```
> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18) 
> Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> ```

Comment: These all work in `bash` release 5.0.7(1). You should probably mention what actually happens when you run this, as well as what your `bash` version is.

Comment: Show your actual output. Also show your bash version: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`

Comment: Why can't you just use `eval`? Yes, you can work around that bug with `source /dev/fd/0 <<<'export foo=bar'` (which will use a regular/seekable tempfile), but it's just as completely pointless as your examples.

Comment: Yeah eval might work - it's for copying commands to current terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would not work in `bash` releases before release 4.0 (for example, the default `bash` on macOS, which is release 3.2.57(1)).

Release 4.0 had a bugfix:

> Fixed a bug that caused `.' to fail to read and execute commands from non-
>       regular files such as devices or named pipes.

(that's from https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)

The file read by `source` (or `.`) when you use it with a process substitution is not a regular file, so it would trigger the bug that was fixed in release 4.0.

The most recent release is currently release 5.0.7(1), where your code works as expected.

Comment: @Alexander, if you are on a mac, install bash via homebrew to get a more recent version.

Comment: Anybody know of a good way to easily switch between bash versions 3 4 and 5 on a machine?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Clone the Git repository (`git://git.savannah.gnu.org/bash.git`) and check out the appropriate tag and build it?

Comment: thanks I used the technique here to build from gnu bash source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522023/since-aliases-are-not-inherited-is-there-any-alternative-to-exporting-the-execu