# Since aliases are not inherited, is there any alternative to exporting the executable on the PATH?

Tags: bash, shell, path

I am trying to setup a system to switch between bash versions on a Mac.
I have this which works:

```
change_bash_version(){

  if test "$1" == "3"; then

    export PATH="$HOME/bash/versions/3.2.57:${PATH}"

  elif test "$1" == "4"; then

    export PATH="$HOME/bash/versions/4.4.18:${PATH}"

  else

    export PATH="$HOME/bash/versions/5.0:${PATH}"

  fi

}

export -f change_bash_version
```

I tried using aliases but they are not inherited - my question is - is there an alternative to changing the PATH to putting the desired bash executable in front? It doesn't work very easily to put an entire directory on the PATH if that dir has a bunch of extraneous files that I don't want the PATH to see.

The other downside to this technique is having to use a bash function to switch versions (unless someone can think of way to use a command line utility).

I tried using this:

```
change_bash_version(){

  bash(){
    $HOME/bash/versions/4.4.18/bash "$@"
  }

  export -f bash;  # error here
}
```

but bash did not like that - saying "bash" is not a function

Comment: As an aside, I followed these instructions to install bash from source - https://gist.github.com/samnang/1759336

Comment: Why not use your `/usr/local/bin` as the first directory in your PATH and have your function create/change a symlink in there to the bash version you desire?

Comment: because that would change it for all shells - I am just looking to change for current shell if possible

Comment: Is bash not the current shell?  If you mean current terminal than why doesn't an alias work?

Comment: aliases don't get inherited by subshells - youre right I meant all terminals - but all shells too I guess

Comment: They do for me.

Comment: What shell do you use? Aliases don't get inherited in Bash.

Comment: I use bash.  Do you mean inherited **from** subshells or **by** subshells?

Comment: nothing is inherited from, I meant by. Try this `alias foo='echo bar' && bash && foo`, you won't get bar echoed.

Comment: you are going to get `bash: foo: command not found`

Comment: I don't get either because it spawns a new environment.  I also get nothing from `alias foo='echo bar' && bash && echo hello` but if I do `alias foo='echo bar'; (foo)` I will get `bar`

Comment: hmmm that's interesting, there must be a difference between what I did and the subshell you have

Comment: if you're in bash, and you spawn a new shell with `bash`, your alias from the parent don't get inherited, but I don't know why they're inherited with the subshell you have

Comment: perhaps that's the difference between a subprocess (child process) and subshell

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29145093/8239155

Comment: yeah one awkward thing with the PATH updating, is the PATH will get really long, I keep appending to it

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me with very basic testing:

```
change_bash_version(){
    case $1 in
        3) bash() { "$HOME/bash/versions/3.2.57/bash" "$@"; } ;;
        4) bash() { "$HOME/bash/versions/4.4.18/bash" "$@"; } ;;
        *) bash() { "$HOME/bash/versions/5.0/bash"    "$@"; } ;;
    esac
    export -f bash
}
```

Comment: yeah but if it doesn't work with bash 3 then I might be able to get out of bash 3, will try it

Comment: so this works according to my testing, and I suppose it's better than appending stuff to the PATH?